# iOS Application to get Direction between two places ( URL scheme )

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, url-scheme

I am developing an iOS application to get directions between two places,I am getting exact directions for some of the places by providing the name of the places directly

[http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino](http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San%20Francisco,%20CA&saddr=cupertino)

But I couldn't get places in some other countries. So I have tried with the geo coordinates

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",latitude,longitude,latitude1,longitude1]]];
```

But its returning a map with different appearance, it looks like some older version. So I want to implement a map something similar as in the first method but its input should be as Geo coordinates.

Comment: Do you want to show the map in your own application or open it outside?

Comment: You best bet is to use the [`MKMapItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011746) to open the Maps.app with direcrions.

Comment: @jithinroy: Yeah I want to show it in outside. Thats y I am trying url scheme. Thanks

Comment: @rckoenes : Thanks for the suggestion, But my requirement is using Google Maps with url scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first URL you used is not Google map, it is Apple map.
Check this link please : [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html)

If you want to use Google map urlScheme use this :

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&directionsmode=transit
```

Details are given in this link : [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme?utm_source=welovemapsdevelopers&utm_campaign=GM-for-iOS-sdk-1-7)

Comment: Oh My bad !!!. So one doubt, Can I use geo coordinates directly in the first method ?

Comment: Oh I have tried it, I think Apple doesnt provide exact route in all location. Am getting locations in US but not in other countries.